# Regex to match anything but more than two spaces

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to create two a regex to add quotes to some values in a string. Basically the string would be like this:

```
999            date               Doe, John E.              London            123456789
```

And I want to surround the name so that if this file is exported to a csv, it won't be separated.  This is what I have so far

```
$line =~ s/([^\s{2,}]*,[^\s{2,}]*)/"$1"/g;
```

I think it should find any comma and anything near it until it finds two or more spaces but it's not working.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can’t put quantifiers inside a pick-just-one-of-these square-bracketed character class. They can’t quantify one to be non-one.

Comment: @tchrist I've used this method before, but not with the qualifying brackets `{}`.  You can use this to return everything after an xml bracket, for instance, like this `/<tag>([^<>]*)/`

Comment: Notice how with `[^<>]*`, the quantifier goes *outside* the square brackets.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  You have pinpointed my mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You asked for anything *except* 2 or more spaces.

I agree that `unpack` is the more natural way to do this.  But `split` is a way to use a cookie-cutter in the shape of a pattern. Anything *not* in that pattern is a return field.  So this:

```
@fields = split /\h{2,}/, $line;
$line = join(" " x 2 => map { "($_)" } @fields);
```

might be enough.

Comment: @atatko: Glad to help. Note that I am using `\h` for *horizontal whitespace*.  This is a new shortcut that first appeared in Perl 5.10. Before that release you had to use `\p{HorizSpace}`, which is so long to type that people would usually just use `\s`, with also gets the *vertical whitespace*, too (which is `\v`).  Even when it doesn’t make a difference with a particular example, I like `\h` because it says more clearly what I mean. But  then you had better put `use 5.10.0;` at the top of your program to signal that you need that minimum version number for the program to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a fixed-width data (and my guess, it is), better use unpack (or plain old substr,etc..) rather than regular expressions.

Comment: It probably looks that way because of my poor example.  It isn't fixed width, neither the data nor the space in between stays constant.  Otherwise I would agree.

Comment: And even if it isn't, maybe `split / {2,}/` would be a better approach than a do-it-all regexp. (Fixed width data often turns out not to be, like if an earlier field has too many digits).

Answer (score 1):

`[]` contain a range of characters that are allowed at that possible, 2-space isn't a character.

Maybe:

```
$line =~ s/  (.*? .*?)  /  "\1"  /g;
```

You'll probably need to be more explicit about the format to avoid matches against ' '.

```
$line =~ s/  (\w+?, [\w ]+?.)  /  "\1"  /g;
```

To avoid repeating the space in the replacement, look-around assertions could be used, which could also fix the issue of items at the beginning and end of the line:

```
$line =~ s/(?<=^|  )(\w+?, [\w ]+?.)(?=$|  )/"\1"/g;
```

Also be careful of your original format - are you sure it isn't just column aligned? (In which case a sufficiently long name or date might not allow 2+ spaces between columns).

Comment: I could say `/\s{2,}*/ /g` to convert everything 2 or more spaces into a single space, is there a way to specify anything **but** 2 or more spaces

Comment: I think you're regex will work for [last], [first] [m] , but this also needs to work when the name is Dr. name name, name PHD Sr.  It really needs to keep finding everything until it hits more than two non-characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s/.*  \K(.*),(.*?)  /"$1,$2"  /
```

Logically, this means: Find a substring between two spaces and a comma, where the two spaces are as far right as possible, and then a substring between that comma and two spaces, where the substring is as short as possible.

Your approach can work too, if you get the syntax for negative lookaheads right.

Answer (score 1):

The sample text you supplied seems to be separated either by tabs or spaces (column aligned?). It is important to know which, or the regexp will not work. It is also important to know whether the pattern is consistent throughout the file.

If it is aligned by columns, the easiest and probably safest way is to simply count off characters. E.g.:

```
s/(^.{20})(\S*)  /$1"$2"/;
```

(You will have to adjust the number 20 yourself. I just approximated.)

Note that I am chopping off two spaces at the end of the name field in a reckless manner. This is to not screw up the format for the following values. If however the field is filled to the brim, there might not be two spaces at the end, and the regexp will miss. But then, on the other hand, you would not be able to fit quotes there anyway.

When dealing with these types of files, I do not think it is safe to use generic searches. If you are counting on commas to only appear in the names, sooner or later you will find someone who thought that "Bronx, New York" should be in the city field, and your regexp will be screwed.

A somewhat more strict, but complicated regexp would include the previous fields:

```
$date='\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}'; # this might work for dates such as 11-10-23

s/^(\d+\s+$date\s+)(\S+)  /$1"$2"/;
```

Same thing here, if the name field is not big enough to fit two quotes, it won't be added. You should check your file and see if that is ever the case. If it is the case, you will need to deal with it somehow.

I sometimes find that putting certain field's regexps in separate variables helps with legibility, such as with $date above.

Good luck!

Comment: Your example of "Bronx, New York" is exactly why this needs to work more dynamically.  My first example may have been overly simple, any of the fields can contain a comma, and when they do it should then be surrounded by quotes.